# Why in Angular, import of a Module has to be in app.module.ts, why can't module be imported directly in component?

Tags: angular, import, module, components, export

Basically, I was learning Angular from [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1).

I got that in app.module.ts I have to import FormsModule

like below code snippet

```
// At app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms"
// import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";          // Commented purposly to check
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    // FormsModule,          // Commented purposly to check
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

now this import I have to do in app.module.ts to make it run the example

**import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";**

but why can't same be imported in heroes.component.ts component directly (check out the example in the mentioned link above)?

like below code snippet

```
// At heroes.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from "../modelClasses/hero";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms"; //**Despite its imported my example is not working if I comment in FormsModule in app.module.ts


@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  hero : Hero = {id: 1,
          name: "Windstorm" }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

because as per my understanding module and components are two different conceptual building blocks of any angular app where module encapsulate many components services directives while component is a smaller part for system.

but also if a class is annotated with component does that mean it can't import modules directly?

Because it's after all a class and module works like a package so ideally exported classes from a package should be available to import in another class.

Can help to understand why such a way I have to import specifically in my app.module.ts file?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules

Comment: Also see if you are confused between ES6 modules and NGModules explained in the guide.

Comment: There I couldn't find answers for my confusion, can explain a bit in layman terms or I better say in terms of Java or C# as I am from Java background